# Regular expression on bash/shell/python for githook pre-commit

Tags: regex, bash, shell, githooks

I am trying to work with regular expression
I have a string in format

```
[+/-] Added Feature 305105:WWE-108. Added Dolph Ziggler super star
```

Let's look on each part of string

```
1) [+/-] – bracket quotes are important. it can [+] or [-]. or [+/-]. not "+", or "-", or "+/-" without bracket quotes
2) Added – it can be "Added", "Resolved", "Closed"
3) 305105 – any numbers
4) Feature – it can be "Feaute", "Bug", "Fix"
5) : – very imporant delimiter
6) WWE-108 – any text with delimiter "–" and with numbers after delimiter
7) . – very imporant delimiter
8) Added Dolph Ziggler super star – any text
```

What I tried to do
Let's try to resolve each part: 
1) `echo '[+]' | egrep -o "[+/-]+"`. Yes, it works, but, it works also for `[+/]`, or `[/]`. and I see result without bracket quotes 
2) `echo "Resolved" | egrep -o "Added$|Resolved$|Closed$"`. It works 
3) `echo '124214215215' | egrep -o "[0-9]+$"`. It works 
4) `echo "Feature" | egrep -o "Feature$|Bug$|Fix$"`. It works too 
5) I have not found how 
6) `echo "WWE-108" | egrep -o "[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+"`. It works too 
7) I have not found how
8) Any text

The main question. How to concatenate, all these points via bash with spaces, according to this template. `[+/-] Added Feature 305105:WWE-108. Added Dolph Ziggler super star`. I am not familiar with regexp, as for me, I'd like to do something like this:

```
string="[+/-] Added Feature 305105:WWE-108. Added Dolph Ziggler super star"
first=$(echo $string | awk '{print $1}')

if [[ $first == "[+]" ]]; then
echo "ok"
echo $first
elif [[ $first == "[*]" ]]; then
echo "ok2"
echo $first
elif [[ $first == "[+/-]" ]]; then
echo "ok3"
echo "$first"
else
echo "not ok"
echo $first
exit 1
fi
```

But it is not ok. Can you please help me in a little bit with creation of regexp on bash. Also, python it is ok too for me.

Why I am doing this ? I want to make pre-commit hook, in format like this.
`[+/-] Added Feature 305105:WWE-108. Added Dolph Ziggler super star`. This is a reson, why I am doing this.

Comment: what about `egrep '^\[(\+|-|\+/-)\] (Added|Resolved|Closed) (Feature|Bug|Fix) [0-9]+:[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+\..+'`, with extended regex a general rule that be considered meta characters `.*+^$(|)[]{}` must be escaped with a backslash to have literal meaning (except in character sets between `[]` where rules are different)

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul thanks. works

Comment: glad to know, comment was changed to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from comment. Putting all together.

```
egrep '^\[(\+|-|\+/-)\] (Added|Resolved|Closed) (Feature|Bug|Fix) [0-9]+:[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+\..+'
```

a general rule, with extended regex, meta characters `.*+^$(|)[]{}\` must be escaped with a backslash to have literal meaning (except in character sets between `[]` where rules are different).

Note, for culture, that with basic regex, it's the contrary, backslash was used to enable the specaial meaning of regex extensions `(|){}+`.

```
grep '^\[\(+\|-\|+/-\)\] \(Added\|Resolved\|Closed\) \(Feature\|Bug\|Fix\) [0-9]\+:[a-zA-Z]\+-[0-9]\+\..\+'
```

But it's longer and harder to understand.